# How to change div height on slideToggle function with more/less

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide, slidetoggle

How can I update my code, so I can change `<div>` height with `slideToggle()`, now it's almost correct, **but** when I click on one `"read_more"` and click to another it's not right. I need when is `slideDown` to show hidden `p` and change the main `<div>` to specific height and when is `slideUp` to hide this `p` and change the `<div>` previous specific height (`"... Read More"` base `.main` height, `"... Read Less"` new `.main` height).

Please see [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4MfLw/) or code below.

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
    <!-- === h1 === -->
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.</p>
        <p class="more">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate.</p>
        <a class="read_more">... Read More</a>
    <!-- === h2 === -->             
    <h2>Consectetur adipisicing elit</h2>
        <p>On the other hand, we denounce with righteous.</p>
        <p class="more">Gemoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment.</p>
        <a class="read_more">... Read More</a> 
    <!-- === h3 === -->                  
    <h3>Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</h3>
        <p>The wise man therefore always holds.</p>
        <p class="more">Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.</p>
        <a class="read_more">... Read More</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main {
    border:1px solid blue;
    height: 260px;
    padding: 5px;
}
h1,h2,h3 {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #96bc33;
}
p {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.more {
    display:none;
}
.read_more {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: red;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var rm = $(".read_more"),
    moreText = "... Read More",
    lessText = "... Read Less",
    i = 0 ;

rm.click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    rm.not($this).text(moreText).prev(".more").slideUp();
    $this.text($this.text() == moreText ? lessText : moreText).prev(".more").slideToggle("normal");
    $(".main").animate({height:(++i % 2) ? 280 : 260}, "normal");   
});
```

Comment: Do you have to set a specific height? If not, just change in your css `.main { height:auto; ... }` and delete the second `click` function.

Comment: thanks @Matt, but yes I need a specific height

Comment: I knew you would want a specific height :-) All the existing answers are now incorrect.

Comment: @onlinepch will a specific `min-height` be ok?

Comment: @andyb thanks so much for the help, on first look it's ok, but when `slideUp` I need the previous height. The idea is when `slideToggle` <div> height change it.

Comment: The answer from @MamaWalter was updated to use a `min-height`. `<div>`s grow and shrink automatically when the content changes _unless_ you set a `height` or `width`

Comment: Hi guys, think I get it, if someone have the same issue like mine, please see the **updated** [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/onlinepch/4MfLw/12/). Thanks again for your help !

Answer (score 3):

I've upgraded your jsFiddle:

> http://jsfiddle.net/GwkQN/

The changes that were done are:

- removed the *height* attribute from your *main* container
- refactored your script for *rm.click*

I'm not sure if your code did something else apart from the slideToggle, but this one-liner probably does everything that you need.

```
$(this).prev('.more').slideToggle();
```

Changed jQuery code:

```
var rm = $(".read_more"),
moreText = "... Read More",
lessText = "... Read Less";

rm.click(function () {

    $(this).prev('.more').slideToggle();

    if($(this).text()==moreText){
        $(this).text(lessText);
    }else{
        $(this).text(moreText);
    }

});
```

Changed CSS:

```
.main {
    border:1px solid blue;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Please don't just link to a demo. All relevant code changes should be added to the answer. StackOverflow will probably outlast jsFiddle.

Comment: You need to update your demo link but `+1` as I know you will fix it soon.

Comment: Done. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 2):

if you need specific height you can use css propertie:  `min-height: 260px;`

```
.main {
    border:1px solid blue;
    padding: 5px;
     min-height: 260px;
}
```

JS

```
var rm = $(".read_more"),
    moreText = "... Read More",
    lessText = "... Read Less";

rm.click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    rm.not($this).text(moreText).prev(".more").slideUp();
   $this.text($this.text() == moreText ? lessText : moreText).prev(".more").slideToggle("normal");
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4MfLw/9/)

Comment: But this *is* a specific starting height. Seems like a nice solution to me, but perhaps @onlinepch if you have specific requirements you could edit the question with them please?

Comment: Thanks so much @andyb, _but_ on my page something isn't right, the Demo look very good, it's a good exercise, hope it help to someone with same issue.

Comment: Hi guys, think I get it, if someone have the same issue like mine, please see the **updated** [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/onlinepch/4MfLw/12/). Thanks again for your help !

Comment: i must be missing something but your demo produce the same result as mine, and i dont need `animate`.

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
jsfiddle.net/4MfLw/8/
```

I have updated your code

I have removed "height" attribute from your css of "main" class
Also I have commented your code of animation and I have written the code to slide up all the other "more" div if they are open

Comment: A link to a demo does not answer the question.

Comment: @andyb I have updated the code and it works fine there

Comment: @SnehalS there's a flag specially for these kind of answers. It's called "link only answers". Andy has a point - at least provide explanation for your changes.

Comment: And if jsFiddle goes down (or goes away for good), how is this still a good answer?